# How can I simply store a number of distribution list criteria/logic in database?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, list

I need to select a distribution list from a list stored in the database based upon two inputs which are the following

- A single customer type (Business or Residential, one or the other, not both, null is not a valid input)
- A single service area (SA1,SA2,SA3,SA4, one and only one)

The logic for determining which list to select is simple and can be determined within a stored procedure.

However the problem comes when attempting to store the determining criteria for each distribution list. The criteria for a distribution list can be any combination of customer types (residential only, business only, residential and business) and service area (for example Residential SA1 is different from Business SA1, is different from Business and Residential SA2). My initial solution was to use two columns customerType and ServiceArea and have comma separate lists that contained the customer types and service area for each distribution list. I would like to avoid that so that my database can maintain some semblance of 3NF.I would also like to avoid have a column for each customer type and each service area.

Is there a way to store this information without comma separated lists and without a column for each value, so that a stored procedure given a single customer type and a single service area select the distribution list that is tied to that combination of customer type and service area?

Comment: A normalized database is what you want.  If you don't know what that means, I've heard good things about the book, Database Design for Mere Mortals.

Comment: I agree, I'm trying to achieve normalization here, just kinda stuck on how to do it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good reason not to stuff the service areas in a comma delimited list in most situations, however, you are storing a user preference setting so the Normal Forms can be relaxed a bit **if** the service area codes are never removed or renamed and only added to. I look at this like storing a user's color preference if it does not cause the system to crash then do what is easiest.

Having said that, if SA1,SA2,SA3... are subject to removal and/or renaming then I would **not** use a list for this. Some relationship similar to below would work if you are required to use 3NF.

**CustomerServiceAreaFilter**
CustomerServiceAreaFilterID(PK)
UserID(FK)
CustomerType(FK)
**Unique Index On UserID and CustomerType

**CustomerServiceAreaFilterServiceArea**
  CustomerServiceAreaFilterServiceAreaID(PK)
  CustomerServiceAreaFilterID(FK)
  ServiceAreaID(FK)
**Uniqe Index on CustomerServiceAreaFilterID ServiceArea

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your customer type and service areas have unique numbers associated with them, and that you know the upper bound of each, you could say that each customer's properties can be turned into a number by doing:

`2 ^ customer type + (2 ^ service area) * 2 ^ (maximum customer type value)`

In practice, for your customers this means each customer will have something like the following:

```
100010
100001
010010
010001
001010
001001
```

left 4 digits are binary of service area, right 2 digits are customer type

Your criteria table could be one with three columns:

```
| distribution_list_id | criteria_id | group |
```

When determining the members of the distribution, query your criteria table for all rows matching a distribution list's id, grouping by the `group` column and selecting sum of `criteria_id`. Select all rows from customers `join` to this criteria table on their calculated bit flags being equal to the customer's type. The purpose of the `group` column is to allow you to `and` things together, whereas separate rows with different `group` values in the criteria table indicate `or`.

Assuming you write well-documented stored procedures to insert into these tables, the whole "changing-into-bit-logic" part shouldn't get too hairy, and the purpose is to allow you to easily do `and` of arbitrary numbers of criteria based on `group` (`sum` is much easier than string concatenation in a `group by`). This way, when inevitably customers get more properties like they always do, you can just add more bits to the end for another set of properties without changing your schema.

Full disclosure, I'm also not very good at databases but I think this satisfies normal form? If not please let me know why in the comments, also trying to learn.

-Edited for typos

Comment: Stuffing all the information into a single column is the opposite of normalization.